# How to wait until function return result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

We have 2 functions:

```
submitEstateObject = () => {
    // if (!this.state.formIsValid) {
    //   this.setState({ showFieldErrors: true })
    //   console.log(this.state)
    // } else {
    //this.setState({ isLoading: true })

    console.log('Category', this.state.estateForm.category.value)
    console.log('Type', this.state.estateForm.type.value)
    console.log('Params', this.state.estateParams)
    console.log('ContactsAndOwners', this.state.contactsAndOwners)
    console.log('Photos', this.state.photos)
    //Submit photos
    const test = this.uploadPhotos() // WAIT UNTILL FUNC RETURN ARRAY!
    //AFTER TEST WAS DONE RUN CODE BELOW
    console.log('Test', test)
    console.log('Test2')
    //}
  }
```

In body of my function you can see, that i'm calling `uploadPhotos`. This func must return array of objects, and after that i want to continue executing another code below. How to do that?

```
uploadPhotos = () => {
    if (this.state.photos.length) {
      const photosToSave = this.state.photos.map(photo => {
        const extensionPattern = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/
        const fileName = photo.value.name
        const fileExtension = extensionPattern.exec(fileName)[1]
        const newFileName = new Date().getTime()
        const fileLocation = storageRef.child('estateObjects/' + newFileName + '.' + fileExtension)

        return new Promise(resolve => {
          fileLocation.put(photo.value).on(
            firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
            snapshot => {
              //let progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            },
            null,
            () => {
              fileLocation.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                resolve({ url: url, file: newFileName + '.' + fileExtension })
              })
            }
          )
        })
      })
      Promise.all(photosToSave).then(response => {
        return response
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: please don't vote - !

Comment: Well you haven't properly explained what is or isn't working, any errors that occur etc or what specific problem is and where in your code you are having issues

Comment: In my code you can see console.log(photosToSave). I want to see array of objects. But now as on screen i can see array of promises!

Comment: i'm to friendly with promises right now. can you get working code as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of handling promises. By a callback (resolve) or by actually returning a promise. I'm going to address the latter.

Every time you return something in a promise, it will be returned as a promise. So you need to wrap calls to functions, that returns a promise, in a promise.

EXAMPLE:

```
function ajaxCall(url) {
  return return AJAXRequest(url);
}

function getSearch() {
  ajaxCall('http://test.com')  // Calling a function that returns an ajax call.
  .then(function (ajaxResponse) {
    // code that handles ajaxRespons
  });
}
```

But in your `uploadPhotos` method, nothing is returned. You need to return your Promise.all.

```
  // the equivalent to my ajaxCall example
  uploadPhotos = () => {
    // other code
    return Promise.all(photosToSave) // added 'return' and removed the return statement inside the Promise.all method.
  }
```

The response should then be handled as a promise.

```
// the same as in my getSearch example
const test = this.uploadPhotos()
.then(function (ajaxResponse) {
  //AFTER TEST WAS DONE RUN CODE BELOW
  console.log('Test', ajaxResponse)
});
```

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Promise.all(promiseArray)`

Instead of `console.log(photosToSave)`

Try

```
Promise.all(photosToSave).then(arr => console.log(arr))
                         .catch(err => console.log('Something failed', err)
```

Comment: That's ok, but can you modify my code. The real need not to console.log. I want to get "photosToSave"  - array of object, and AFTER I GET all values, i want to move next (to make another things). Or just make things in then block?

Comment: @charlietfi i have updated my question. Can you check it please

Comment: So you do it in the `then` above. The log is just there to show where to access and consume your data

Comment: Is there way to do as i described in updated question? If i'll continue in then block my parent func will be very complicated. In my case the best way to move uploadPhotos to stand alone function, as i described in question

Comment: You can return the Promise.all and then do `uploadPhotos().then(data=>console.log(data))`